# Boundary condition in perpetual american option problem

Tags: stochastic-calculus, american-options, stochastic-control, stopping-time

I am trying to solve the perpetual American option problem. Currently I'm following [this](https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/2964) (slide 9). The stock price is modelled as Ito's process.

> $dS_t = (\mu-D_0)S_tdt\ +\ \sigma S_tdW_t $

where $D_0$ is the dividend. Basically the problem tries to find optimal stopping time to exercise the option i.e. we try to optimize the value function $V(S)$ w.r.t stopping time $\tau$.

> $V(S) = \sup_{\tau \in T}\ \mathbb{E}[e^{-r\tau}\max(S_\tau -K,\ 0)] $

Once we have the Value function $V(S)=AS^\beta$, we use the boundary condition at optimal time to get relation between $A$ and $S^*$.

> $V(S^{*})=S^*-K$

To get [another relation](https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/2964) (slide 12) for solving for both $A$ and $S^*$ we try to maximize $A$ so as to increase the value function as much as possible. I do not see any justification for this.

Contrary to the derivation in the above reference, another [reference](http://scik.org/index.php/mfl/article/view/2519) (equation 6) uses smooth pasting condition i.e.

> $V'(S^*) = f'(S*)$ ; $\ \ f(S) = S-K$

The difference in the techniques to obtain the second relation between $S^*$ and $A$ leads to different solutions. I'm not convinced with the argument of maximizing $A$. So if anybody can justify it, it'd be great. Also which solution is actually *optimal*?

Thanks :)